# MVC 4.5 DataAnnotations working through Visual Studio 2013 but not from iis?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
```

I use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model =>
```

when I run the app through visual studio, the data-val attributes show in the page source,  but when I run the same app from my iis server, the input tag does not show any of the data-val attributes?

What am I missing?

I do have the `~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js` and `~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` at the bottom of my `_layout.cshtml`

Comment: I am using jquery 2.1.4.min and jquery-ui-1.11.4.min

Comment: I do not get any script errors.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to answer without more information but one possibility is dlls missing from the website on iis. Check if the bin folder on vs have any dlls not present in iis.

Comment: I just checked and all the dll's in vs are present in iis.

Comment: What additional info would you need?

Answer (score 0):

OK, seems as though

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```

was the culprit.  Once I removed it, now it works.

Comment: <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>